# How to configure Xcode to fetch swift dependencies over ssh using a private key which is stored on a Yubikey ( HSM , gpg --card-status )

Tags: xcode, ssh, git, gpg

Problem currently is that I find no way to simply configure or instruct Xcode to check out source code or dependencies over git+ssh using ssh agent.

Does Xcode at all supports using the `ssh-agent`?

I have not found any possibility to configure it without refering to its private key. (usually referred to `~/.ssh/id_rsa` etc around on the web)

Sadly I have no way of referring to the private key in Xcode when it is stored inaccessible for anyone else then the Yubikey (HSM).

Meta information:

My gpg-agent is configured into my environment and works flawless in the terminal with some simple setup:

```
export GPG_TTY=$(tty)
gpg-connect-agent updatestartuptty /bye
unset SSH_AGENT_PID
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$(gpgconf --list-dirs agent-ssh-socket)
```

(See https://www.engineerbetter.com/blog/yubikey-ssh/ for details on yubikey setup)

`gpg --card-status` lists that my keypair is available, and it works in the terminal as `ssh-agent -L` lists my public key and I can use it to ssh into remote hosts accepting my ssh key or issue `git clone..` in the terminal.

Comment: @OmarChaabouni Sadly no, and I currently moved to another project where I do not use an Apple product and xcode. I guess the best way to get support for this is probably to reach out to Apple and ask if they can look into supporting this.